# Vite bundles `@firebase` peer dependency for library

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vite

I've been writing a hook+component library for React and Firebase, the source of which can be seen [here](https://github.com/erayerdin/firereact).

It reached to a certain stability. My current goal is to reduce the size as much as possible. I've checked documents and stuff and this is the `vite.config.ts` that I have:

```js
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import { peerDependencies } from "./package.json";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/index.ts", // Specifies the entry point for building the library.
      name: "firereact", // Sets the name of the generated library.
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`, // Generates the output file name based on the format.
      formats: ["cjs", "es"], // Specifies the output formats (CommonJS and ES modules).
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(peerDependencies)], // Defines external dependencies for Rollup bundling.
    },
    sourcemap: true, // Generates source maps for debugging.
    emptyOutDir: true, // Clears the output directory before building.
  },
  plugins: [dts(), peerDepsExternal()], // Uses the 'vite-plugin-dts' plugin for generating TypeScript declaration files (d.ts).
});
```

`build.lib.rollupOptions.external` is to be expected: It gets peer dependencies from `package.json`. `peerDepsExternal` helps to not bundle the dependencies of peer dependencies.

Still, I've thought the final size is not that reasonable compared to some similar libraries.

That's why I've checked what's being included with `npx vite-bundle-visualizer`.

[image: vite-bundle-visualizer report]

Seems like `@firebase` is being included to the final library. I can also confirm it with `less dist/index.es.js` and see `@firebase` being mangled.

Firebase is a peer dependency so it shouldn't be bundled to the final library (or maybe I misunderstand something cruicial about `peerDependencies`).

How do I exclude `@firebase` from the library?

---

## Troubleshooting

Here are some ways that I've tried to remove `@firebase` from the final library:

- Tried to manually add it into `build.lib.rollupOptions.external` in `vite.config.ts`.
- Played  with some settings in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the submodules of `@firebase` are bundled. The solution for me was:

```js
  external: [
    "@firebase/firestore",
    "@firebase/auth",
    "@firebase/util",
    "@firebase/storage",
    "@firebase/app",
    "@firebase/functions",
    "@firebase/component",
    "@firebase/logger",
    "react",
    "react/jsx-runtime",
    ...Object.keys(peerDependencies)
  ], // Defines external dependencies for Rollup bundling.
```